# Does neovascularization help or hinder healing in a tendinopathy?

Tags: blood, tendinopathy

Many studies have shown that tendinopathies often come with neovascularization in the injured area. Does neovascularization help or hinder healing in a tendinopathy?

---

From http://inside.akronchildrens.org/2013/10/16/causes-symptoms-and-treatments-for-tennis-elbow/, it sounds like neovascularization help heal a tendinopathy:

> HORNER: We call it tennis elbow. What do you call it?
>
> DR. CONGENI: You want the medical term? It’s called tendinopathy or
>   tendinosis. It means now it’s not just tendinitis anymore. If you
>   looked under a microscope at your tendon, instead of being a nice
>   shock-absorbing tendon tissue, it’s got all this junkie scar tissue as
>   the body tries to heal this overload injury.
>
> HORNER: Once you have it, do you always have it?
>
> DR. CONGENI: No. The good news about it is there’s this thing called neovascularization, and what that means is new blood vessels go into the area and repair the tendon. It repairs itself, but it takes a long time.

However, (1) hypothesized that eccentric exercises are effective to heal a tendinopathy as they reduce the neovascularization.

---

- (1) Öhberg, Lars, and Håkan Alfredson. "Effects on neovascularisation behind the good results with eccentric training in chronic mid-portion Achilles tendinosis?." Knee Surgery, Sports Traumatology, Arthroscopy 12, no. 5 (2004): 465-470.
  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=12045385379743078652&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22

> The occurrence of a neovascularisation in the area with
>   tendon changes, demonstrated with colour Doppler examination
>   simultaneously with ultrasonography, has been
>   shown to possibly be correlated with pain in chronic midportion
>   Achilles tendinosis[13]. In that study, it was demonstrated
>   that passive dorsiflexion of the ankle stopped
>   the flow in these vessels (area with neo-vascularisation)
>   (Fig. 1a, b)
>
> […]
>
> In a recent pilot study on patients with chronic midportion
>   Achilles tendinosis, sclerosing the area with neovascularisation
>   outside the ventral part of the tendon cured
>   the pain in the majority of patients [14]. The results of this
>   study indicate that the area with neovascularisation (neovessels
>   and accompanying nerves) might be the source of
>   pain in the chronic stage of this condition
>
> […]
>
> Four patients (four tendons) did not wanted to participate
>   in the follow-up.
>   At follow-up after treatment (mean 28 months, range
>   3–48), there was a good clinical result (no tendon pain
>   during loading) in 36/41 tendons, and a poor result in 5/41
>   tendons.
>   In 34/36 tendons with a good clinical result of treatment
>   there was an ultrasonographically more normal tendon
>   structure, and in 32/36 tendons there was no remaining
>   neovascularisation (Fig. 2a, b). In 4/36 tendons with a
>   good clinical result from treatment a minor neovascularisation
>   remained, and in 2/36 tendons there were remaining
>   structural abnormalities. In 5/5 tendons with a poor
>   clinical result there was a remaining neovascularisation in
>   the tendon, and in 2/5 tendons there were remaining structural
>   abnormalities.
>
> […]
>
> The results from the current study indicate that there
>   might be something in the eccentric training regimen that
>   affects the area with neovascularisation. It is difficult to
>   explain exactly how the eccentric exercises have influence
>   on the area with neovessels, but using dynamic ultrasound
>   and colour Doppler examination we have demonstrated
>   that during the heel-drop the flow in the neovessels
>   is stopped, whilst in the resting position there is flow
>   again (Fig. 1a, b). Theoretically, if the flow is stopped 180
>   times/day (the eccentric program consists of 180 repetitions/
>   day), this might, directly or indirectly, hurt the neovessels
>   and accompanying nerves.

Andres, Brett M., and George AC Murrell. "Treatment of tendinopathy: what works, what does not, and what is on the horizon." Clinical orthopaedics and related research 466, no. 7 (2008): 1539-1554. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=7561813467505274045&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 are inconclusive when talking about sclerotherapy (= injecting a chemical into a blood
vessel, which results in sclerosis of that vessel):

> Sclerotherapy involves injecting a chemical into a blood
>   vessel, which results in sclerosis of that vessel. Polidocanol
>   was used as the sclerosing agent in all of the studies.
>   Polidocanol is not FDA-approved although other sclerosing
>   agents are. The rationale behind using sclerotherapy in
>   tendinopathy is based on the finding that there is a proliferation
>   of small blood vessels in areas of tendinopathy.
>   Nerve fibers appear to travel in close proximity to these
>   areas of neovascularization [24, 95, 97]. It is possible these
>   nerve fibers are the pain generators in tendinopathy. In
>   theory, injecting a sclerosing agent into the areas of
>   neovascularization could not only sclerose the vessels, but
>   also may eradicate the pain-generating nerve fibers.
>
> […]
> Although polidocanol injections appear to provide
>   pain relief, it is unclear what role they may play in
>   tendon healing in tendinopathy. Intuitively, one would
>   think sclerosing the neovessels of a damaged tendon
>   would be detrimental to tendon healing and could possibly
>   even cause more damage. Polidocanol injections do
>   appear safe, however.